# Chainlink async bridge task returns HTTP Error 422

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

I have to integrate my Chainlink Bridge task with an asynchronous call. Looking at the official [documentation](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/task-types/task_bridge), there's the parameter named `async` and I can set it to `true` to invoke it asynchronously.

I also found this [link](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/external-adapters/developers/#asynchronous-callbacks) which explains how to create `Asynchronous callbacks`.

I created the following job step:

```ini
fetch           [type="bridge"
                 name="generate-hash"
                 requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": {\\"fileList\\": $(decode_cbor.fileList)}}"
                 async=true
                ]
```

I also set the environment variable [BRIDGE_RESPONSE_URL](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/configuration#bridge_response_url) equals to my Chainlink Oracle address. Looking at the documentation, I must set when using async external adapters.

If I start the job execution, I can see the async call to my bridge and it contains the `responseURL` equals to `{BRIDGE_RESPONSE_URL}/v2/resume/{id}`.

Once the process finishes, I call the `responseURL` using the PATCH http method with the following body:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "fileList": ["aaa...fff", "bbbb...vvvv"],
    "hashList": ["0x...", "0x..."]
  }
}
```

The error I get is `422 - Unprocessable Entity`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed the problem looking at the `DEBUG` logs on the Chainlink Node. My logs were these ones:

```
2023-01-17T21:49:01.538Z [DEBUG] PATCH /v2/resume/b5c2254d-6f85-4953-9f63-7911951a3fb4 web/router.go:535                
body={"data":{"fileList":["aaa...fff","bbb...vvv"], hashList":["0x...","0x..."]}} clientIP={client_ip} ùerrors=Error #01: must provide only one of either 'value' or 'error' key
```

Even if the official Chainlink documentation says you have to send back the result or the error setting `data` or `error`, it's wrong.

You have to set the parameter `value` and then you can set the parameter `data` inside. This is how I updated my PATCH HTTP request body:

```json
{
  "value": {
    "data": {
      "fileList": ["aaa...fff", "bbbb...vvvv"],
      "hashList": ["0x...", "0x..."]
    }
  }
}
```